# Ruby Gem won't build: Gem::InvalidSpecificationException [...] are not files

Tags: git, rubygems

I am trying to build a gem, but I keep getting:

```
WARNING:  See http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/ for help
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InvalidSpecificationException)
  [*list of about 300 file paths*]
are not files
```

I know the files must be added to git, and I have done so. Everything is up to date.

What Strikes me is that the file paths in the list are those of is a subdirectory, but the path is missing several folders.

Example:

```
In list: bin/some_file.jar
Actual file: bin/some_library/lib/some_file.jar
```

I suspected it has to do with how my git is set up, because my gem is in a "mother git folder" which has several projects, including a couple of gems, like so:

```
Mother Folder
  -> .git
  -> GemFolder1
  -> GemFolder2
  -> SomeOtherProject
```

It appears that I am amble to both build and install Gem1, but Gem2 gives me these errors.

Initially I had a folder with `.` in the folder name, so I thought that was the problem. So I renamed the folder, added all the changes to git, and retried. However, I still had the same exact issue.

I think this is very strange, and it makes me suspect there is some strange bug in Gem itself.

Furthermore, when I manually run

```
`git ls-files -z`.split("\x0")
```

in Ruby, the files that show up as "are not files" initially don't even exist in this list.

What is going on here?

Comment: In most cases the git line is probably the main reason of causing trouble, and a starting point for debugging this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out what was causing this:

I had the default settings in my gemspec file, this creates the line:

```
spec.executables   = spec.files.grep(%r{^bin/}) { |f| File.basename(f) }
```

What happens is that any file in a subfolder within the `bin` folder will be stripped away from the files path, so `bin/some_folder/some.executable` will be transformed into `bin/some.executable`.

This is, in my opinion a bug in the defaults from bundler.

Because i had a very small gem I simply solved this by writing:

```
spec.executables   = []
```

I believe I won't need my files registered as executables (I might be wrong).

What you also could do is write:

```
spec.files.grep(%r{^bin/}) { |f| f[3..-1] }
```

This will be a more suitable solution for most people. For me, it didn't work because I had some non-executable files in there causing problems.

Hope this helps someone out there :)

Comment: `spec.files.grep(%r{^bin/}) { |f| f[3..-1] }` solved my problem exactly. thank you! did you file this issue with `bundler`? i do think it is a bug.

Comment: @AlexMoore-Niemi I didn't see your message until now, 5 years later. And no; I did not file this as a bug. I have since pivoted away from Ruby almost entirely.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that

```
s.files         = `git ls-files`.split("\n")
```

was originally written as

```
s.files         = `git ls-files`.split('\n')
```

...with single quotes.  Changing that fixed it for me, not sure why it broke in the first place though...

Comment: I had it with single quotes and I got the same error. Changing it to double quotes solved it for me. Weird...

Answer (score 0):

###### I was with the same problem after rename the gem package.

What solved to me:

1 - Read generated gemspec

```
 # Specify which files should be added to the gem when it is released.
 # The `git ls-files -z` loads the files in the RubyGem that have been added into git.
```

2 - Run

```
git add YOUR_EDITED_FILES # or git add .
git commit -m "ENTER_A_MESSAGE_DESCRIPTION_FOR_YOUR_COMMIT"
```

3 - Build your gem

```
gem build your_gem.gemspec
```